# Small screen fragment always appear and it won't go

Tags: 14.04, gnome

I am using **Ubuntu 14.04 Genome Version 3.12.2** and this small fragment (shown in picture below) appears occasionally and it won't disappear unless I reboot the system. But, the strange part is sometimes it automatically disappears while spread my window.

[image: fragment shown with arrow]

Comment: Which graphics card/chip?

Comment: Intel® Ivybridge Desktop @MichaelBay